# How to add different CSS3 hover transitions on hover out with CSS

Tags: css, hover, css-transitions, transition, css-transforms

my question relates specifically to attempting a different CSS background transition on hover out, than the transition for hover in, using CSS.

This question references the CSS3 hover effects available at [Ian Lunn GitHub CSS3 Hover effects](http://ianlunn.github.io/Hover/)

[See codepen here](http://codepen.io/barnus/pen/EKbxqN), or view code below. 
Code:

```
<style>

.hvr-shutter-in-horizontal {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
    background: rgba(121,61,61, 0.7);

    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
    transform: translateZ(0);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition-property: color;
  transition-property: color;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
}
.hvr-shutter-in-horizontal:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
    background: rgba(77,79,79, 0.7);

  -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
  transform: scaleX(1);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50%;
  transform-origin: 50%;
  -webkit-transition-property: transform;
  transition-property: transform;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}
.hvr-shutter-in-horizontal:hover, .hvr-shutter-in-horizontal:focus, .hvr-shutter-in-horizontal:active {
  color: white;
}
.hvr-shutter-in-horizontal:hover:before, .hvr-shutter-in-horizontal:focus:before, .hvr-shutter-in-horizontal:active:before {
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
  transform: scaleX(0);
}
</style>


<a href="#" class="hvr-shutter-in-horizontal">View our Training Workshops</a>
```

I would like to change the mouse-out for this button, to be the same mouse-out as the following CSS produces:

```
/* Sweep To Bottom */
.hvr-sweep-to-bottom {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition-property: color;
  transition-property: color;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
}
.hvr-sweep-to-bottom:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #2098d1;
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(0);
  transform: scaleY(0);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0;
  transform-origin: 50% 0;
  -webkit-transition-property: transform;
  transition-property: transform;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}
.hvr-sweep-to-bottom:hover, .hvr-sweep-to-bottom:focus, .hvr-sweep-to-bottom:active {
  color: white;
}
.hvr-sweep-to-bottom:hover:before, .hvr-sweep-to-bottom:focus:before, .hvr-sweep-to-bottom:active:before {
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(1);
  transform: scaleY(1);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a sample of the concept, which animate the height on mouse over and the color on mouse out

*Based on a comment it's updated with a pseudo element*

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  height: 30px;
  background: red;
  transition: background 1s;
}
div:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
  transition: background 1s;
}

div:hover {
  height: 120px;
  background: blue;
  transition: height 1s;
}
div:hover:after {
  top: 100%;
  background: yellow;
  transition: top 1s;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, yeah I've seen this one. Can't quite get it to work with the above transitions though. Requires a good understanding of :before and other pseudo-elements I guess

Comment: @Barney Added a pseudo to my sample